# Can I pass className and methodName at runtime to ClassVisitor() and methodVisitor() in ASM parser after started the server?

Tags: java, compilation, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I have started learning (I am new to this) , ASM API for a compiler project . I am using java Instrumentation and ASM ByteCode Library for developing a Javaagent.

I am passing classname and method name through properties.My goal is to change my className and methodName at run runtime ( means that after server started or premain() is called).

But , It works only for whatever the className or packageName passed at before started server.

I understand that , while calling the javaagent ( premain() ) , ASM set visitor for method for given pakage/class.

Even after server started or premain() is called , I wanted to visit to a specific class and method.

It Will be very helpful , if any one help on this.

This is my currently running program.

```
        public class AddPrintlnAgent implements ClassFileTransformer {

    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {
     Properties prop = new Properties();

    try {
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\locator.properties"));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    inst.addTransformer(new AddPrintlnAgent());
}

public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className,
        Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain,
        byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {

    byte[] retVal = null;

    if (className.equals(className)) {
        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(0); 
        ClassVisitor ca = new MyClassAdapter(cw); 
        ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(classfileBuffer); 
        cr.accept(ca, 0); 
        retVal = cw.toByteArray();
    }
    return retVal;
}

public class MyClassAdapter extends ClassNode implements Opcodes { 
    private ClassVisitor cv; 
     Properties prop = new Properties();
    public MyClassAdapter(ClassVisitor cv) { 
        this.cv = cv;  

    } 
    @Override 
    public void visitEnd() { 
        try {
            prop.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\locator.properties"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         for (MethodNode mn : (List<MethodNode>) methods) {
             if (mn.name.equals(prop.getProperty("methodName").trim())) {
            InsnList il = new InsnList();

            il.add(new FieldInsnNode(GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;"));
            il.add(new LdcInsnNode(prop.getProperty("message")));
            il.add(new MethodInsnNode(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", 
                        "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V"));
            mn.instructions.insert(il);

            mn.maxStack +=2;                    
            }
        }
        accept(cv); 
    } 

}
```

}

Thanks in advance

Sathish V J

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, but `if (className.equals(className)) {` should always return true, thus re-writing your bytecode for every class. Also, what exactly do you mean by "change my className and methodName"? Are you planing on changing the names of certain classes and methods?

Answer (score 0):

You should cleanup your code. In your `premain` method you load a properties file into a `Properties` object but that instance is never used. Instead you reload that file into another `Properties` instance at every `visitEnd()` invocation. I’m not sure whether this is really what you want.

However, transformers are invoked during class loading but not for classes that have been loaded already. You can try to retransform or redefine loaded classes, but changing class or method names after loading is not supported by instrumentation.